# Multiple recursive calls

Tags: c++, recursion, time-complexity

I know what a recursive function is and how I can visualize every recursive call on top of the stack. But I have no idea how to think when the function make multiple calls to itself like

```
float foo(int n){

   int a = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       a += 1;

   if (n > 2)
       return foo(n/2) + foo(n/2); // What happens here?

    return a;
}
```

Shall I think of two different stacks now or what is the best way to visualize the result?

Comment: That's a very roundabout way of writing `int a = n;`

Comment: Yes the problem was originally about the time-complexity of the function..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other answers mentioned, there is only one stack and recursive calls evaluated strictly in given order.

However, for analysis purpose, you can visualize entire call sequence as a tree.
[image: Call tree for <code>foo(n)</code>]

Comment: Is every level of this tree a call on the stack? I.e level 1 represents foo(n/2) + foo(n/2) in this case and so on? And I start pop() at the bottom of the tree?

Comment: Every path on the tree from root to leaf is stack state (in some point of execution). your stack will look like: `foo(n)` -> `foo(n), foo(n/2)` -> `foo(n), foo(n/2), foo(n/4)` -> ... ->  `foo(n), foo(n/2), ..., foo(3), foo(1)`. Then it reaches `foo(1)`, it pops `foo(1)` from the stack and proceeds to its sibling, when all siblings are processed, it pops `foo(3)` and proceeds to its sibling, and so on. So your stack will never contain more than `height of tree` frames.

Answer (score 1):

```
return foo(n/2) + foo(n/2); // What happens here?
```

The first expression evaluates completely prior to the second one evaluating.  There's nothing to do with two different stacks.  One stack with the first call expands and contracts as it is evaluated, and once this expression is completely evaluated the second begins.

Does that help visualize it?

Answer (score 1):

> Shall I think of two different stacks now or what is the best way to
>   visualize the result?

It's still a single stack.  In this line:

```
   return foo(n/2) + foo(n/2); // What happens here?
```

... first one of the calls to foo() will be evaluated (with its arguments and local variables pushed on to the stack, used, and then popped off of the stack again), and then the other one will be evaluated in the same way.  (Note that it is undefined in the language spec which foo() call will be evaluated first, so it's up to the compiler's implementers to decide what order they prefer).

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to visualise stack (yes, there is only one stack) for different stages of call foo(4):

before calling foo(4): **caller-stack**

within original call foo(4): stack=**caller-stack, foo(4)**

when foo(4) is within the first call to foo(2): **caller-stack, foo(4), foo(2)**

foo(4) within the first call to foo(2), where foo(2) has already called first foo(1): **caller-stack, foo(4), foo(2), foo(1)**

after returning from first foo(1): again **caller-stack, foo(4), foo(2)**

foo(4) within the first call to foo(2), where foo(2) has  called second foo(1): **caller-stack, foo(4), foo(2), foo(1)**

after returning from second foo(1): again **caller-stack, foo(4), foo(2)**

after returning from first foo(2): **caller-stack, foo(4)**

foo(4) is within the second call to foo(2): **caller-stack, foo(4), foo(2)**

foo(4) within the second call to foo(2), where foo(2) has already called first foo(1): **caller-stack, foo(4), foo(2), foo(1)**

after returning from first foo(1): again **caller-stack, foo(4), foo(2)**

foo(4) within the second call to foo(2), where foo(2) has  called second foo(1): **caller-stack, foo(4), foo(2), foo(1)**

after returning from second foo(1): again **caller-stack, foo(4), foo(2)**

after returning from second foo(2): **caller-stack, foo(4)**

after returning from foo(4): **caller-stack**